# Python Script to play a Vimeo Video

Tags: python, video

I want to have my script open a webpage and click on the video to play it.

All I have so far is:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://vimeo.com/95250540")
```

Which will open the webpage but now I need to click on the video.

I've looked at urllib and selenium but am quite lost. Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python module `subprocess` and bash command `xdotool` . With the help of these tools you can make an python script.

You can try mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import webbrowser,subprocess
from time import sleep
webbrowser.open("https://vimeo.com/95250540")
sleep(30) # You can adjust it according to you internet speed.
subprocess.call(["xdotool","mousemove","800","500","click","1"])
```

**Note:** `800` and `500` are approximate coordinates of point inside `div` containing that video , you may change them according to you screen size.